# Sequelize: Require vs Import

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

In the documentation for sequlize they use the import function like so

```
// in your server file - e.g. app.js
var Project = sequelize.import(__dirname + "/path/to/models/project")

// The model definition is done in /path/to/models/project.js
// As you might notice, the DataTypes are the very same as explained above
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define("Project", {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    description: DataTypes.TEXT
  })
}
```

However, what would be so wrong with this?

```
// in your server file - e.g. app.js
var Project = require(__dirname + "/path/to/models/project")

// The model definition is done in /path/to/models/project.js
  var Project = sequelize.define("Project", {
    name: Sequelize.STRING,
    description: Sequelize.TEXT
  });
module.exports = Project
```

Comment: mmm good point, I just copied from the online documentation. In the actual code I am doing what you suggested.

Comment: imho having the models project a package is a great idea. However it's been difficult to integrate that concept into my sequelize projects due to the default approach sequelize takes of reading models in from directories. Thanks for this question as it's given me fresh inspiration to require the models from a package.

Comment: I checked out the source code. The only difference I can see is it is caching the import based on path. Requiring and invoking shouldn't be a problem because the cache seems only relevant to import.

Answer (score 13):

Well, as you can see your model definition needs two things:

1. Sequelize or DataTypes
2. sequelize

In your first example when using `sequelize.import('something');` it is similar to use `require('something')(this, Sequelize);` (*this* being the *sequelize* instance)

Both are necessary to initialize your model, but the important thing to understand is: One of these is a classtype so it's global, the other one is an instance and has to be created with your connection parameters.

So if you do this:

```
 var Project = sequelize.define("Project", {
    name: Sequelize.STRING,
    description: Sequelize.TEXT
  });
module.exports = Project
```

Where does sequelize come from? It has to be instantiated and passed somehow.

Here is an example with require instead of import:

```
// /path/to/app.js
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize(/* ... */);
var Project = require('/path/to/models/project')(sequelize, Sequelize);

// /path/to/models/project.js
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    sequelize.define("Project", {
       name: DataTypes.STRING,
       description: DataTypes.TEXT
    });
};

module.exports = Project
```

You could even change it so you wouldn't have to pass *Sequelize* by requiring it in the model itself, but you would still need to create a *sequelize* instance prior to define the model.

Comment: This saved my a$$! Thank you so much.  I needed to pass parameters to my models and could not do so with sequelize.import().  For example I can now pass my environment object `app` like so

require('/path/to/models/project')(sequelize, Sequelize, app)

Answer (score 0):

**`sequelize.import` is deprecated as of sequelize 6**

As mentioned at https://sequelize.org/master/manual/models-definition.html

> Deprecated: sequelize.import
>
> Note: You should not use sequelize.import. Please just use require instead.

So you should just port:

```
// index.js
const sequelize = new Sequelize(...)
const User = sequelize.import('./user')

// user.js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  // Define User.
  return User;
}
```

to:

```
// index.js
const sequelize = new Sequelize(...)
const User = require('./user')(sequelize)

// user.js
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize')
module.exports = (sequelize) => {
  // Define User.
  return User;
}
```